# Jenkins shell script execution on different server

Tags: jenkins, docker

I have two VM, on one VM I have docker and on another I have Jenkins .I have shell script for running docker, which is placed on server which have docker on it. But I need Jenkins to execute this shell script, from pre-build step.

I am facing problem with this process.
It will be very helpful if any one can provide the detail steps

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

There are different approaches to achieve that.

One is to install *Jenkins slave* on the VM which has docker on and have your *Jenkins master* run the *whole* job on the slave.

Or you could install one of [Publish Over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) or [SSH plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin) to execute commands remotely (if your docker VM has SSH access)

Answer (score 1):

If your network is sufficiently secured from the outside, you could expose the docker API socket via a TCP port on your docker-machine and run the docker commands from your jenkins machine, using the remote tcp-port.

Basic idea is outlined [here](https://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/) in the section "Bind Docker to another host/port or a Unix socket"

Cheers D